# Adding UIImagePickerController as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add a UIImagePickerController in a custom frame, so have been following a few posts around adding the UIImagePickerController view as a subview.

A couple of questions:

- How would I adjust the frame of this subview?
- After adding as a subview, touch seems to be disabled (I can't browse photos or press the cancel button), how would I solve this?

Many thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;

//This is a subview of self.view. 
[self.pickerControllerHolderView addSubview:self.imagePicker.view];

// This seems to adjust the size of the view, but squashes the view. 
// self.pickerControllerHolderView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internals of this class are private and it is not meant to be added as a subview. It is a self contained view controller and navigation controller and will most likely not work how you expect it to. If you need custom UI for picking photos, you should access the `ALAssetsLibrary` and display the contents yourself.